# How to set up a git repo that works on Windows and Linux in Android Studio (and using gradle)

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea, android-studio

I want to work on code on my Windows machine and Mint machine.

The project is in Android Studio and is built using Gradle.

How much of the project should I check into the git repo?  Do I commit the iml and gradle files?  I see there is a local.properties that says it should not be committed.

Comment: Search for `IntelliJ` instead of `Android Studio` and you'll find answers which files you should add to version control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define and commit a proper `.gitignore` file for Android Studio (and in my opinion for IntelliJ/Eclipse too). The `.gitignore` tells you what kind of files you don't want git to track. This is one of many examples for Android projects:

```
# Eclipse
.project
.classpath
.settings
.checkstyle

# IntelliJ IDEA
.idea
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
classes
gen-external-apklibs

# Gradle
.gradle
build

# Maven
target
release.properties
pom.xml.*

# Ant
bin
gen
build.xml
ant.properties
local.properties
proguard.cfg
proguard-project.txt

# Other
.DS_Store
tmp
```

It is from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/castorflex/6065817). In addition you should look on Google repo where iosched 2013 is. There is also a nice example of `.gitignore` [(reference)](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/.gitignore).