# .gitignore for Android Studio project with developers using Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: git, android-studio

Which is the ideal .gitignore file for a project involving developers using Android Studio from Ubuntu and Windows OS? The classic .gitignore for an Andoird Studio project is

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

But in this case I had to add `/.idea/gradle.xml` since in Windows the gradle.xml cannot resolve `$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$` and uses the specific Windows path, so this file should be untracked.

Are there other files which should be ignored?

PD: I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615508/how-to-set-up-a-git-repo-that-works-on-windows-and-linux-in-android-studio-and) but it does not seem to offer a proper solution.

Comment: In every project, all files that come from building/compilation are not to be uploaded to repository. Check what files are created from compilation (temporary files, binaries, etc) and add them to .gitignore. This is the general way of working for any kind of project. Only source code (and/or useful documentation) should be uploaded to repositories.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However this is a gradle problem where some path variables are not understood. In any case, ignoring that specific file was enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use the one provided by

https://github.com/github/gitignore

and specifically the Android .gitignore

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore

Comment: @bfg does it helps?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but anyway I don't see where the gradle.xml would be ignored. Any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a good solution:

```
# Android Studio
*.iws
*.iml
.idea
.gradle

build/
*/build/

captures/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Windows thumbnail db
Thumbs.db

# OSX files
.DS_Store
```

Comment: This looks like a complete .gitignore file, I will give it a try. Still, I found that the problem is also how Android Studio is configured, as the original .gitignore was working on a certain Windows OS but failing on another one. So the configuration of Android Studio made that error happen.